# Why is Label object not callable appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am in the process of making an OOP Countdown GUI with the letters, numbers and conundrum games.
This is a snippet of my code so far.

```
  class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.title("Main")
      self.configure(bg=LIGHT_BLUE)
      self.title=tk.Label(master=self,bg=LIGHT_BLUE,font=("Arial",12,"bold"),text="!Countdown Games!",pady=5,padx=5)
      self.title.pack()
      self.frame=tk.Frame(master=self,bg=LIGHT_BLUE)
      self.LettersButton=tk.Button(master=self.frame,bg=LIGHT_BLUE,font=("Arial",12,"bold"),text="Letters",command=self.start_letters)
      self.LettersButton.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="NESW",pady=10,padx=2)
      self.NumbersButton=tk.Button(master=self.frame,bg=LIGHT_BLUE,font=("Arial",12,"bold"),text="Numbers",command=self.start_numbers)
      self.NumbersButton.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="NESW",pady=10,padx=2)
      self.LettersButton=tk.Button(master=self.frame,bg=LIGHT_BLUE,font=("Arial",12,"bold"),text="Conundrum",command=self.start_conundrum)
      self.LettersButton.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="NESW",pady=10,padx=2)
      self.frame.pack()
      self.mainloop()

    def start_letters(self):
      self.withdraw()
      self.Letters=Letters()

    def start_numbers(self):
      self.withdraw()
      self.Numbers=Numbers()

    def start_conundrum(self):
      self.withdraw()
      self.Conundrum=Conundrum()


  class Conundrum(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.configure(bg=LIGHT_BLUE)
      self.geometry("400x150")
      self.title("Conundrum")
      self.frameA=tk.Frame(master=self,bg=LIGHT_BLUE)
      self.letterList=[]
      self.answer=r.choice(ninewords)
      self.anagram=anagram(self.answer)
      for x in range(9):
        self.letterList.append(ConundrumDisplay(self.frameA,x))
      self.frameA.pack()
      self.frameB=tk.Frame(master=self,bg=LIGHT_BLUE)
      self.letterEntryList=[]
      for y in range(9):
        self.letterEntryList.append(ConundrumEntry(self.frameB,y))
      self.frameB.pack()
      self.timer=tk.Label(master=self,bg=LIGHT_BLUE,font=("Arial",12,"bold"),text="31")
      self.update_timer()
      self.timer.pack()
      self.mainloop()
      m.showinfo("Startgame","The game will start when you press OK")
      for x in range(9):
        self.letterlist[x].add_letter(x,self.anagram)
      self.bind("<Key>",self.process_key)
      self.bind("Return",self.process_guess)
      self.bind("BackSpace",self.process_back)
```

The upper bit of code is a method from an App class which inherits from tk.Tk
The error is in the super()._ _ init _ _() line in the conundrum class after you press the Conundrum button in the main wn
This conundrum class is obviously the bit of code just below which inherits from tk.Toplevel.
I have used tk.Toplevel before but it hasn't shown the error before.
I have tried to reduce the amount of code that I am posting but if any more of it is necessary to figure out the error, then I can amend the question.

Error Message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "main.py", line 50, in start_conundrum
        self.Conundrum=Conundrum()
      File "main.py", line 55, in __init__
        super().__init__()
      File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2624, in __init__
        self.title(root.title())
    TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: it may be good to send `parent`/`master` to widgets - ie `Conundrum(root)` and `def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Probably `root.title` is a `Label`? Please demonstrate some debugging effort.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: you can't call a `Label` as if it was a function.

You are doing this: `self.title(root.title())`. `root.title` is an instance of `Label` but you are trying to call it as if it was a function. You get the same error if you do something like this:

```
foo = Label(...)
foo()
```

Since `foo` is a `Label` rather than a function, you can't call it.

If you want to call the `title` function of the root window, you should not name the label `self.title`. Name it something else so that you can use the `title` method of the base class.